# How do have two constraints on a UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, handles

I have this code below.  It works if i use only ONE WHERE variable but the moment i add another one, the query doesn't work.

It works if i just use this one all unions:

```
       where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
```

But when i use this one below, it doesn't work:

```
      where table_constant.user_id = '$uid' and table_one.something <> '$uid'
```

Code:

```
  $sql = "select table_one.field1, table_constant.field1, 
table_one.field2, table_one.field3, table_one.field4, 
table_one.field5, table_constant.c_id
from table_one LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_one.field1 
= table_constant.c_id 
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid' and table_one.something <> '$uid'
UNION
select table_two.field1, table_constant.field1, table_two.field2, 
table_two.field3,    table_two.field4, table_two.field5, table_constant.c_id
from table_two LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_two.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id 
where table_two.added_by = '$uid' and table_two.something <> '$uid'
UNION 
select table_three.field1, table_constant.field1, table_three.field2, 
table_three.field3, table_three.field4, table_three.field5,
table_constant.c_id
from table_three LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_three.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid' and table_three.something <> '$uid'
UNION
select table_four.field1, table_constant.field1, table_four.field2, 
table_four.field3, table_four.field4, table_four.field5, 
table_constant.c_id
from table_four LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_four.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid' and table_four.something <> '$uid'
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the result?

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to show some data that should give a result but doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought I have a decent guess as to what the problem might be. When you write a LEFT JOIN, I presume you do so because there might be some rows that don't match anything on the right side of the join. If you'd like to constrain those rows that *do* match in some way, you need to do so in the `JOIN` itself. For example:

```
LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_one.field1 = table_constant.c_id AND table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
```

By placing the second condition in the `WHERE` clause, you're essentially turning the left join into an inner join by forcing the right side to have a value.